# Multiplying two dictionaries

Tags: c#, performance, dictionary

Is there a more optimal way to do the following -

```
int interactionScore = 0;

        foreach (var completionResult in needs.Keys.Intersect(results.Keys))
        {
            interactionScore -= results[completionResult] * needs[completionResult];
        }
```

both needs and results are small dictionaries (around 2 - 10 entries each) but the number of times I run this loop is very high and it is hurting my performance, so I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to achieve similar results (multiplying only entries which exist in both dictionaries).

Comment: Can't you cache the result? Do dictionaries change?

Comment: First benchmark, what's the limiting factor? Calculating the intersection of the dictionaries or running the loop over the result?

Comment: They are expected to change. Not completely, so I will be doing some caching if I am unable to find a better solution, but it will be quite a hassle.

Comment: The Profiler claims the interation inside the Intersect method is the biggest culprit.

Comment: If it helps somehow, I am running the same "needs" through several "results" but the score needs to be separate for each intersection so my guess is it doesn't help ^^''

Comment: Does the variable `completionResult` represents a key that exists in both dictionaries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Avoid `Intersect`

```
int interactionScore = 0;
foreach (var key in needs.Keys)
{
  if (results.TryGetValue(key, out int result))
  {
    int need = needs[key];
    interactionScore -= result * need;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah! TryGetValue. Forgot about that. This should allow me to not have to iterate again after already finding what I need.

Comment: Well, this function no longer shows up high in the profiler, so this was the solution. Thanks!

Comment: *"Avoid Intersect"* <=== Correct. The [`Intersect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect) method is intended for enumerables that may include duplicate values. The keys of a dictionary are guaranteed to not include duplicate values (according to the specified `IEqualityComparer`), so using `Intersect` for dictionary keys is overkill.